# Remotely connect Ubuntu to windows over internet

Tags: 14.04, windows-8

how to remotely connect to another computer over the internet window,can I do it by Remmina Remote desktop client?Can anyone tell me a way out.I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and the remote desktop is running on WIndows 8

Answer (score 2):

You can use TeamViewer: http://www.teamviewer.com/

It's very easy to install in any Operating System and very easy to connect (you just need to introduce the ID and PIN of the computer you want to control).

Comment: so the Windows user need to install the teamviewer application ?and can I remotely log in from my ubuntu machine to use the windows 8 machine..

Comment: 1) Yes 
2) Yes
all you need to do is get the ID and PIN provided by the program running on the computer you want to control and introduce them in the computer from which you want to control the other.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use

`Remmina Remote desktop client`

Its one of many available, and you do not need 3rd party software like Team Viewer.

Other apps for that that you can use on ubuntu are:

```
Remotedesktop Client,2X Client RDP / Remote Desktop
```

you can also use `rdesktop` from terminal

With any of those you do not need anything installed on the windows machine